# Where are JavaDocs generated by Gradle if default is not set?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, gradle

I am running the Gradle Javadoc task (through java plugin) but I cannot find the output.

In the gradle documnetation it states that the default destination directory is `${project.docsDir}/javadoc`, however I cannot find where `${project.docsDir}` is set. What is the output location when `${project.docsDir}` is not set?

***Update:** I had built the project using the `idea` plugin which builds a project with the `build` directory excluded/hidden; it also excludes/hides the `.gradle` directory. This also explains where the complied classes where disappearing to.*

Comment: have you looked in `build/docs` of your project?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings is `build/docs` the default value of `${project.docsDir}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`build/docs/javadoc` is the output directory.

Comment: The documentation says that the doc is generated in project.docsDir. And it generates it in build.docs. What do you conclude?